# Can I toggle one element and at the same time hide the others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, show-hide

I've been looking around for a while but I'm afraid I'm too begginer for this easy jquery.

I´ve tried show/hide and toggle functions but I don´t find the way to show toggle elements in a page hidding the others. The toggle works, but when I click one I'd like the others to be hidden and I don't find the way. Maybe It's too easy, but I can't find the answer.

This is my jquery

```
function toggleDiv(divId) { $("#"+divId).toggle();}
```

And this is the html sample

```
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('div1');">Toggle Button 1</a>
<div id="div1">
<p>paragraph 1</p>
</div>
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('div2');">Toggle Button 1</a>
<div id="div2">
<p>paragraph 2</p>
</div>
```

I´ve just created a fiddle that explains better what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/vKLNe/

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry about my english.

Comment: you need to hide all other div in your javascript function

Comment: If you click twice on the same element, should that element be hidden?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `class="toggle"` to all the divs that toggle and then
http://jsfiddle.net/vKLNe/5/

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    $("#"+divId).toggle();
    $('.toggle').not($("#"+divId)).hide();
}
```

Comment: And if the user wants to hide the div that is already shown without showing another ?

Comment: @NathanP. it has been updated so it can hide clicked one too.

Comment: You can write `.not("#"+divId)` directly also :)

Comment: @NathanP. I see, it doesn't have to be a jQuery object. Nice to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Shoot someone beat me to it... but yeah you can use toggle or show because you are manipulating multiple divs before you show the current clicked div...

```
function toggleDiv(divId) { 
    $('div').hide();
    $("#"+divId).toggle();
}
```

The only downfall is that if you decide to have different divs doing different things, it could cause issues with them.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are ways to do that on your own like Freddy's and Adam's, you can always rely on some kind of pre-defined accordion like jquery ui's

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Or bootstrap's collapse

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

And you wouldn't have to worry about handling the events yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by css classes.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/vKLNe/4/

Use hide and show classes

and only one div at a time will have show class.

html:

```
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('div1');" style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 5px 10px;">Toggle Button 1</a>

<div class="hide" id="div1" style="background-color: #aaa; padding: 5px 10px;  width:200px;">
<p>paragraph 1</p>
</div>
<br /><br />


<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('div2');" style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 5px 10px;">Toggle Button 2</a>

<div class="hide" id="div2" style="background-color: #aaa; padding: 5px 10px;  width:200px;">
<p>paragraph 2</p>
</div>
 <br /><br /> 



<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('div3');" style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 5px 10px;">Toggle Button 3</a>

<div class="hide" id="div3" style="background-color: #aaa; padding: 5px 10px;  width:200px;">
<p>paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    $(".show").addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
    $("#"+divId).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
}
```

css:

```
.hide {

    display: none;
}
.show {
 display: block;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is **MUCH** more practical to use event listeners compared to inline JS:

**jQuery in**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // listen for clicking of the <a>
    $('a').on('click', function(e){
        // don't let the <a> perform it's default action
        e.preventDefault();

        // hide all divs
        $('div').hide();

        // show the <div> which is after the <a> which you clicked
        $(this).next('div').show();
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- notice the <a> tags have an href="#", no more inline JS! -->
<a href="#" style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 5px 10px;">Toggle Button 1</a>

<div id="div1" style="background-color: #aaa; padding: 5px 10px; display:none; width:200px;">
    <p>paragraph 1</p>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<a href="#" style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 5px 10px;">Toggle Button 2</a>

<div id="div2" style="background-color: #aaa; padding: 5px 10px; display:none; width:200px;">
    <p>paragraph 2</p>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<a href="#" style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 5px 10px;">Toggle Button 3</a>

<div id="div3" style="background-color: #aaa; padding: 5px 10px; display:none; width:200px;">
    <p>paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

Please not that this code ONLY works because you are not doing any animations such as fading or sliding. `.hide()` and `.show()` merely change the CSS the moment they are called upon where as `.fadeIn()` will alter the CSS potentially thousands of times over a specified period of milliseconds.

http://jsfiddle.net/vKLNe/8/